# WYSIWYG Editor cms page media list not display

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

WYSIWYG Editor cms page media list not display but image exist on media/wysiwyg/ .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check your flash player is updated or not if not updated then updated it.

check this files is loaded browser/js.phtml and /browser/content.phtml and check permission of media folder 777